# Shared event handler for XML views with different controllers

Tags: event-handling, sapui5

Given two XML Views:

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="my.namespace.controller.First"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
  xmlns="sap.m">

  <Button press=".onBtnPress" />
</mvc:View>


<mvc:View
  controllerName="my.namespace.controller.Second"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
  xmlns="sap.m">

  <Button press=".onBtnPress" />
</mvc:View>
```

As expected, the press  event is handled by `First.controller.js` or `Second.controller.js`.

**Instead of duplicating the event handler code or implementing handlers in each Controller to chain/hand off the work, I want to declare a shared event handler.**

According to [docs](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/b0/fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe/content.htm) this should be possible, using a naming convention for the handler:

> Names starting with a dot ('.') are always assumed to represent a method in the controller.
>
> Names containing a dot at a later position are assumed to represent global functions and are resolved by calling jQuery.sap.getObject with the full name.

So I change the handler and declare a shared object, like so:

*First.view.xml:*

```
<Button press="my.namespace.Shared.onBtnPress" />
```

*Shared.js:*

```
jQuery.sap.declare("my.namespace.Shared");

  my.namespace.Shared = (function() {

    var onBtnPress = function() {
      console.log("button pressed");
    };

  return { onBtnPress : onBtnPress };
}());
```

Warning logged (debug sources) during view initialisation:

> sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView#__xmlview1: event handler function "my.namespace.Shared.onBtnPress" is not a function or does not exist in the controller. -

Calling `jQuery.sap.getObject("my.namespace.Shared")` yields `undefined`

Same issue when using `sap.ui.define` to make the object known.

Answer (score 2):

Since UI5 1.69, it has become easier to *share JS modules in XML view and fragment.*<sup>[doc](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/b11d853a8e784db6b2d210ef57b0f7d7)</sup>

Here is an **example: https://embed.plnkr.co/5G80I5HWObCuM5cG**

> ```xml
> <mvc:View controllerName="..."
>   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
>   xmlns="sap.m"
>   xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
>   core:require="{ onButtonPress: 'my/shared/onButtonPress' }">
>   <Button text="Press" press="onButtonPress" />
> </mvc:View>
> ```

As we can see, each button displays a different message depending on the view, even though the handler itself isn't included in the controller definition.

The `this` context is still the controller instance as documented in the topic [*Handling Events in XML Views*](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe):

> As long as no event handler parameters are specified and regardless of where the function was looked up, it will be executed with the controller as the context object (`this`).

Answer (score 0):

Your shard object looks weird

Try something like this:

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
  return sap.ui.base.Object.extend("my.namespace.Shared", function() {
    onBtnPress : function() {
      console.log("button pressed");
    }
  };
});
```

Also remember to put the object in the right directory.

Comment: thanks for the assist, but unfortunately this is not it. As mentioned, I also went down the route of using sap.ui.define - guess I will have to prepare a sandboxed example and return to this question.

Comment: You could also try to create a super controller and let the other two extend that. Than it is also more object orientated ... tomorrrow i will post an example

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy-paste your `sap.ui.define` and verified it was created correctly `jQuery.sap.getObject`.

**Make sure that your `sap.ui.define` has been called *prior* to your view being rendered.**

You can set a breakpoint in the [XMLTemplateProcessor](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/XMLTemplateProcessor.js#L398) where the event callbacks are handled for XML views for further debugging/timing issues.

If you look in the `_resolveEventHandler` function it should take you [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/mvc/View.js#L754) which will perform the `jQuery.sap.getObject`.