# UI5: how to reuse formatter in other views?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

```xml
<Text text="{ parts: [ '/firstText', '/number' ], formatter: '.NumberFormatter' }" />
```

I have this formatter in my XML view which is defined in the controller. It works fine, everything is good.

How can I reference and use this formatter in another XML view? To keep it DRY.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shared event handler for XML views with different controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514335/shared-event-handler-for-xml-views-with-different-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually formatters are in their own JS file

Your project structure:

```
- webapp
|-- controller
  |-- First.controller.js
  |-- Second.controller.js
|-- util
  |-- Formatter.js
|-- view
  |-- First.view.xml
  |-- Second.view.xml
|-- Component.js
|-- index.html
```

Your Formatter.js might look like this

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        NumberFormatter: function (sText, iNumber) {
            ...
        },
        MyOtherFormatter: function(...) {
            ...
        }
    };
});
```

Now every controller has to reference the Formatter to make it available in your view.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "../util/Formatter"
], function (Controller, Formatter) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("demo.controller.First", {

        formatter: Formatter, // < Important

        onInit : function () {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Finally you can use it in your view

```xml
<m:Text text="{
        parts: [ 
            'myModel>firstText',
            'myModel>/number'
        ],
        formatter: '.formatter.NumberFormatter'
    }" />
```

---

See [Step 23](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de) of the highly recommended official walkthrough which answers 95% of all beginner questions!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the formatter as a pure<sup>[<sub>?</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)</sup> static function module:

   ```js
   sap.ui.define([ // E.g. in "./model/numberFormatter.js"
     // ...
   ], function(/*...*/) {
     "use strict";
     // ...
     return function(/*...*/) {
       return /*...*/;
     };
   });
   ```
2. Require and use that formatter anywhere you want. For example, in the view definition using the [`core:require`-syntax](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/b11d853a8e784db6b2d210ef57b0f7d7) (supported as of UI5 1.69):

   ```xml
   <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
     xmlns="sap.m"
     xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
     core:require="{
       myFormatter: 'mynamespace/model/numberFormatter'
     }">
     <Text text="{ parts: [/*...*/], formatter: 'myFormatter' }" />
   </mvc:View>
   ```

Unless the formatter doesn't require a controller reference, encapsulating it as shown above keeps the controller code clean and the formatter also becomes easier to unit-test.